# Getting correct direction of the Car

Tags: ai, coordinates

I am building a car racing game using the coordinate system in which I have enemies's cars and the player cars. I want to ask that what is the best way to find the the direction of enemies's cars so that they would facing the player's car and move towards the player's car.

Comment: Isn't this the same as your other question? http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/56088/ai-in-car-game-using-coordinate-system

Answer (score 3):

If you mean that you want the direction for the enemies to face so that they're looking at the player's car, it's literally just maths. You need to calculate the vector between the enemy and the player, and then normalise it so it's a direction. Code example:

```
Vector3 direction = Vector3.Normalise(player.position - enemy.position);
```

Comment: You should also note that (player.Position - enemy.Position) would also provide you with the distance between the two, prior to Normalizing.

Comment: @Jon Fair enough, although I don't know how useful that would be to the OP